# Preventing developer message to user frontend

Tags: laravel-9

I am developing a website with different pages, and among those pages,
I have a contact form that send message to the backend, the email id is unique, I need to display an error message to the front end that if a user enter the email that exist to then it has to display a message the email is taken. How can I go to achieve this. Here is my code

```
Controller
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Contact;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
class FrontendPages extends Controller
{
    public function About(){
        return view('frontend.pages.about');
    }//end method
    public function Service(){
        return view('frontend.pages.services');
    }//end method
    public function Blog(){
        return view('frontend.pages.blog');
    }//end method
    public function Contact(){
        return view('frontend.pages.contact');
    }//end method

    public function StoreMessage(Request $request){
        Contact::insert([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'subject' => $request->subject,
            'message' => $request->message,
            'created_at' =>Carbon::now(),
        ]);
        if ($request->email == 'email') {
            
            return response()->json(['email exist']);
        }
        $notification = array(
            'message' => 'Thank for being in touch we will get back to you soon', 
            'alert-type' => 'success'
        );

        return redirect()->back()->with($notification);
    }
}
```

my form

```
@extends('frontend.main_master')
 @section('main')
 @php
$footersetup = App\Models\Footer::find(1)->first();
@endphp

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- ======= Breadcrumbs ======= -->
      <section id="breadcrumbs" class="breadcrumbs">
        <div class="container mt-3">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <h2>Contact</h2>
            <ol>
              <li><a href="{{url('/')}}">Home</a></li>
              <li>Contact</li>
            </ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- End Breadcrumbs -->

      <!-- ======= Contact Section ======= -->
      <section id="contact" class="contact">
        <div class="container">
         

          <div class="row mt-5">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <div class="info">
                <h4>Location:</h4>
                <div class="address">
                  <i class="bi bi-geo-alt"></i>
                  &nbsp;  
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;{!! $footersetup->address !!}<br /><br />
                </div>

                <div class="email">
                  <i class="bi bi-envelope"></i>
                  <h4>Email:</h4>
                  <p>
                    {{$footersetup->email}}<br />{{$footersetup->email1}}
                  </p>
                </div>

                <div class="phone">
                  <i class="bi bi-phone"></i>
                  <h4>Call:</h4>
                  <p>{{$footersetup->phone}}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-8 mt-5 mt-lg-0">
              <form
                action="{{route('store.message')}}"
                method="post"
                role="form"
              >
               @csrf
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="name"
                      class="form-control"
                      id="name"
                      placeholder="Your Name"
                      required
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
                    <input
                      type="email"
                      class="form-control"
                      name="email"
                      id="email"
                      placeholder="Your Email"
                      required
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mt-3">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    name="subject"
                    id="subject"
                    placeholder="Subject"
                    required
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mt-3">
                  <textarea
                    class="form-control"
                    name="message"
                    rows="5"
                    placeholder="Message"
                    required
                  ></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="my-3">
                 
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send Message</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- End Contact Section -->
   @endsection
```

[image]

Comment: Use [Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation)

Comment: how go about it

Comment: I recommend learning the basic concepts of laravel by following this series! https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch